# Avoiding leaks with __weak

Tags: memory-leaks, sprite-kit, objective-c-blocks

In sprite kit, I've been trying to work out why my SKScene won't deallocate and I believe I have finally taken a step closer to the answer: I use a lot of `SKAction`s with `completion` blocks. I have just learned that I must use weak references.

How do I properly do this? Does **everything** inside the block have to be weak? For example, I just recently changed one of my blocks to look like this:

```
__weak typeof(self.heli) weakheli = self.heli;

    [weakheli runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:1.0f duration:1.0f] completion:^{
            ghostMode = NO;
    }];
```

Do I also have to make a `__weak typeof(ghoseMode) weakGhostMode = ghostMode` statement and only change `weakGhostMode` inside the block?

As another example, should:

```
[weakSelf runAction:[SKAction waitForDuration:.1f] completion:^{
    if (mgFiring) {
        [self fireMG];
    }
}];
```

Be changed to:

```
[weakSelf runAction:[SKAction waitForDuration:.1f] completion:^{
    if (mgFiring) {
        [weakSelf fireMG];
    }
}];
```

Thanks for the help! When I was learning Sprite Kit through tutorials, we were never warned about using `completion` blocks with strong references.

Comment: How do you know your `SKScene` isn't being released? Did you test your game with Instruments?

Comment: @0x141E For one, yes I have tested it with instruments and every time I init a new game scene, the memory goes up and never comes back down. Two, I have `NSLog`'ed the `dealloc` method of my `SKScene` and it is never called.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you provided that would retain the `SKScene`.

Comment: @0x141E well, the scene is being retained and instruments found leaks, so I'm not sure what else to do?

Comment: Did adding weak pointers to all of your actions resolve the issue?

Comment: @0x141E It resolved the leaks, but the scene still isn't being deallocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not require __weak because the heli object is used to run the action, it is not referenced **inside** the block.

```
__weak typeof(self.heli) weakheli = self.heli;

[weakheli runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:1.0f duration:1.0f] completion:^{
        ghostMode = NO;
}];
```

So this will be fine:

```
[self.heli runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:1.0f duration:1.0f] completion:^{
        ghostMode = NO;
}];
```

Same goes for this:

```
[weakSelf runAction:[SKAction waitForDuration:.1f] completion:^{
    if (mgFiring) {
        [weakSelf fireMG];
    }
}];
```

It should be:

```
[self runAction:[SKAction waitForDuration:.1f] completion:^{
    if (mgFiring) {
        [weakSelf fireMG];
    }
}];
```

The weakSelf is only needed (if at all) inside the block.

Comment: why is a weak version of ghostMode not required?

Comment: also, can I leave them as using the weak variable to call the action? I already went through and changed 130 of them to that.

Comment: ghostmode is a bool? it can't be weak then, it's not an object.